# Returning 2d array using pointer to an array in c

Tags: c, pointers, 2d

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*createArray())[3] {
    static int arr[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    return arr;  
}

int main() {
    int (*ptr)[3] = createArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code while returning 2d array why we write like this 'int (*createArray())[3]'.while writing function, we use

```
return_type function_name ( parameter_list)
{
   // function body
}
```

But in this code why we need to write function name between the return type

Comment: I recommend you create a type-alias instead, like `typedef (*array_type)[3];`. Then you could use it like any other type: `array_type createArray(void) { ... }`

Comment: As for the declaration `int (*createArray())[3]` you could follow [the clockwise/spiral rule](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html): `createArray` is a function taking no arguments (in this context!) and returns a pointer to an array of three `int` elements.

Comment: Regarding the note about arguments and context, the declaration `void foo();` declares a function that takes an *indeterminate* number of arguments, all of indeterminate type. This will change with the C23 standard though. Before C23, you should explicitly use `void` if you don't want any arguments.

Comment: The syntax needs to distinguish from other cases of similar syntax - function pointers are similar. As for why... bad design decisions were made during the creation of C. The syntax for array pointers and function pointers is gibberish. And that the language is not able to copy or return arrays is nonsense. It is what it is, far too late to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in this code why we need to write function name between the return type

In C, declarations are written to give a “picture” of how a variable will be used. Kernighan and Ritchie wrote, in *The C Programming Language*, 1978, page 90:

> The declaration of the pointer `px` is new.
>
> `int *px;`
>
> is intended as a mnemonic; it says the combination `*px` is an `int`, that is, if `px` occurs in the context `*px`, it is equivalent to a variable of the type `int`. In effect, the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear. This reasoning is useful in all cases involving complicated declarations. For example,
>
> `double atof(), *dp;`
>
> says that in an expression `atof()` and `*dp` have values of type `double`.

So `int (*createArray())[3]` says:

- The type of `(*createArray())[3]` is `int`.
- Therefore `(*createArray())` is an array of 3 `int`.
- Therefore `createArray()` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`.
- Therefore `createArray` is a function returning a pointer to an array of 3 `int`.

So the need to embed the name inside the declarators arises out of the decision to make a declaration be a picture of how the name will be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem if the function will return pointer to VLA.

The only workaround is to return `void *` but the caller has to remember what pointer is returned.

Example:

```
void *allocateAndRand(const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
{
    int (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array));

    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            array[row][col] = rand();
    return array;
}

void *print(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            printf("%d ", array[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return array;
}

#define MAXROW  50
#define MAXCOL  50

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    size_t rows = rand() % (MAXROW) + 1;
    size_t cols = rand() % (MAXCOL) + 1;

    int (*array)[cols] = allocateAndRand(rows,cols);
    if(array) print(rows, cols, array);
    free(array);
}
```